# Cannot implicitly convert type to System.Collections.IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

> Additional information: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Test.Models.Tables' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The issue is coming at foreach var item in Model. How should I fix this?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ABC()
    {
        var model = new Test.Models.Tables();

        string ABC = "ABC";

        model.TableA = db.TablesA.Where(d => d.IssueKey.Contains(ABC)).ToList();

        model.TableB = (from d in db.TablesA.Where(d => d.IssueKey.Contains(ABC)).ToList()
                              join j in db.TablesB.ToList() on d.Name equals j.ID
                              select new TableB() { DisplayName = j.DisplayName });
        return View(model);
    }
```

Model:

```
namespace Test.Models
{
    public class Tables: DbContext
    {
        public IEnumerable<TableB> TableB { get; set; }
        public List<TableA> TableA { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@using System.Linq
@{ IEnumerable<Test.TableA>TablesA = ViewData["TableA"] as IEnumerable<TableA>;
   IEnumerable<Test.TableB>TablesB = ViewData
   ["TableB"] as IEnumerable<TableB>;
}

@foreach (var issue in Model){
```

Comment: This code is in a mess I'm afraid. You are confusing your model with your context (why does the model inherit from `DbContext`?) And what is the model type of your view here, I assume it's `Tables`? But the error you see is because you are trying to loop through a `Tables` class when you should be, I assume, looping through one of it's properties e.g. `foreach(var issue in Model.TableA)`.

Comment: This code works and is running. I was using @foreach(Issue issue in Model.Issue) before, but I'm calling from 5 different tables, 10 columns total, so it is inconvenient to do that. I'm trying to simplify down to in Model to make it easier.

Comment: It may be inconvenient, but you can't loop over a class that itself isn't enumerable!